# parse XML file and skip tags

Tags: java, xml

I want to retrieve the values of jar under test tag. I am using DOM parser, Could someone help me on the same.

```
<test name="1">
<jar>3</jar>
<jar>4</jar>
<subcomponent name="1">
   <jar>5</jar>
</subcomponent>
</test>
<test name="2">
<jar>8</jar>
<jar>9</jar>
<subcomponent name="2">
   <jar>11</jar>
</subcomponent>
</test>
```

Now, I want to retrieve only <jar> below <test> and ignore <jar> under <subcomponent>. Typically, the code below.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setValidating(false);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(file);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("test");
for(int temp = 0; temp < nodeLst.getLength(); temp++){
   Node nNode = nodeLst.item(temp);
   Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
   NodeList jarsList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("jar");
}
```

With the above code, I get all the <jar> below <test>
Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify the question? The code you posted works or not?

Answer (score 2):

You should really take a look at [xpath](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi.html). It was built exactly for your situation.

I think this would be your needed xpath:

```
//test/jar
```

or if `test` doesn't necessarily need to be the direct parent of `jar`:

```
//test//jar[not(ancestor::subcomponent)]
```

*With the Java part I'm sorry but I can't help you.*

Comment: Thanks, for the xpath example link.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the root element, and then get all its children elements with tag-name="jar":

```
Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
java.util.List<Node> jars = new java.util.ArrayList();
NodeList children = root.getChildNodes();
int length = children.getLength();
for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
  Node current = children.item(i);
  if(current.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE && "jar".equals(current.getNodeName())) {
    jars.add(current);
  }
}
```

Please let me know if it doesn't work, I can't check this right now.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I am missing the code, current.getType() cannot find symbol is displayed.

Comment: Thanks, able to retrieve the values.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to filter them out manually

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setValidating(false);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(file);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("test");
for(int temp = 0; temp < nodeLst.getLength(); temp++){
   Node nNode = nodeLst.item(temp);
   Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
   NodeList jarsList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("jar");
   ArrayList<Element> testJars = new ArrayList<Element>();
   for(int temp2 = 0; temp2 < jarsList.getLength(); temp2++ )
   {
      Node nNode2 = jarsList.item(temp2);
      Element eElement2 = (Element) nNode2;

      if (eElement2.getParent(equals(eElement))) testJars.add(eElement2);
   }
   // testJars now contains the elements taht you want

}
```

Bit of an ineloquent solution, but it fits

Comment: However, I do agree with Alin, the javax.xml.xpath route is much cleaner (since 1.5)

Comment: Ok, I tried the code, above and no value is added to the testJars. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, I got it... Finally able to retrieve the values.